# Creating an X for tic tac toe game in Pygame

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, python-turtle

So I was making a Tic Tac Toe Game with Pygame but I am finding difficulty in drawing an X with the pen tool.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Tic Tac Toe")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width = 800, height = 600)
wn.tracer(0)


# Vertical left line
v_left = turtle.Turtle()
v_left.speed(0)
v_left.shape("square")
v_left.color("white")
v_left.shapesize(stretch_wid = 20, stretch_len = 1)
v_left.penup()
v_left.goto(-100, 0)

# Vertical right line
v_right = turtle.Turtle()
v_right.speed(0)
v_right.shape("square")
v_right.color("white")
v_right.shapesize(stretch_wid = 20, stretch_len = 1)
v_right.penup()
v_right.goto(100, 0)

# Horizontal up line
h_up = turtle.Turtle()
h_up.speed(0)
h_up.shape("square")
h_up.color("white")
h_up.shapesize(stretch_wid = 1, stretch_len = 25)
h_up.penup()
h_up.goto(0, 70)

# Horizontal down line
h_down = turtle.Turtle()
h_down.speed(0)
h_down.shape("square")
h_down.color("white")
h_down.shapesize(stretch_wid = 1, stretch_len = 25)
h_down.penup()
h_down.goto(0, -70)

# X Mark
x_mark = turtle.Turtle()
x_mark.speed(0)
x_mark.shape("square")
x_mark.color("blue")
x_mark.shapesize(stretch_wid = 5, stretch_len = 5)
x_mark.penup()
x_mark.goto(0, 0)

# Main Game Loop
while True:
  wn.update()
```

I want to tilt it like at 45 degrees the left stick of the X Mark and the right stick at 135 degrees. But I want those two sticks to be together no matter where I drag them with my mouse.

Comment: This is not [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) it is [Turtle graphics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)

Comment: Okay, so what happens when you run the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? What do you mean about "dragging them with my mouse"?

Comment: I meant the X Mark (shape) should move with my mouse cursor.